# Cast of pointer to vector of different types

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, casting

I have a function that requires a pointer to vector of type `uint16_t`. This function fills the vector with the data. I have also object that should hold the data but in form of the vector of type `uint8_t`. My code looks as following:

```
void fill1(vector<uint16_t> *data);
void fill2(vector<uint64_t> *data);

class Object
{
    uint32_t data_depth;
    vector<uint8_t> data;
}

Object object1;
object1.data_depth = 16;
fill1((vector<uint16_t>*) &object1.data);

Object object2;
object2.data_depth = 64;
fill2(vector<uint64_t>*) &object2.data);

// somewhere later in the code
if (object1.data_depth == 16)
   vector<uin16_t> * v = (vector<uint16_t>)(&objec1.data);
```

Is it the save way of pointer conversion of vector of different types?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bad idea. And why isn't fill a member function of Object?

Comment: It's not safe. It's wrong as the vector contains other information besides the raw data

Comment: I think the best way to go about this is to copy the data from your uint16 to another uint8 (or vice versa) while performing actual data conversion from one type to another for each element if needed, I donno myself (so you are not actually copying, you are creating new data based on the old ones)

Comment: I use the vector<uint8_t> to hold just raw information. Actually I forget to say that the Object itself knows that the data depth is 16 bit. So when I will to access the data of Object I handle it as 16 bit values.

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish here. Are you trying to store the raw bytes and access them as individual bytes or are you trying to store 16-bit values in an 8-bit vector (which would result in truncation)? Either way, casting the vector is certainly wrong. You might be able to get away with it by casting the underlying array pointer.

Comment: OK, amend that question, are you trying to assign an array of uint8_t to an array of uint16_t or are you trying to reinterpret an 8-bit array as though it contains 16-bit values?

Comment: What I am trying to achive is: The fill method can required any data depth. For example, it can be uint16_t, uint8_t or uint64_t. So I want to do so that Object can hold any data format independent what data depth the fill function return back. And I can access the data of Object correctly by taking the value of data_depth into account.

Comment: @Joel, yes, I will handle the data of Object in this case as vector of 16 bit values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void fill(vector<unsigned char>& data)
{
    assert(data.size() % sizeof(T) == 0);

    T* pReinterpreted = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[0]);
    size_t count = data.size() / sizeof(T);

    // do some stuff with your array of reinterpreted values
}

class Object
{
    uint32_t data_depth;
    vector<unsigned char> data;
}

Object object;
fill<uint16_t>(object.data);
```

Naturally, this is unsafe code so I wouldn't do it unless you know exactly what the trade-offs are here.

Comment: You probably should use `unsigned char` instead of `uint8_t`, to comply with the aliasing rules.  But yes, casting the address of the first (or any) element is the right approach.

Comment: Yeah, and come to think of it you can't really have a generic fill and then use uint16_t* inside the function.

Comment: You could if `fill` were a template, and you used `T*`, where `T` could be `uint16_t` or any other primitive type.

Comment: You forgot to remove `data_depth` from the call.

Comment: I know, it was like magic.  I type the word template in a comment and seconds later the code changes to use templates.

Comment: Thank you for your code. It is good solution. But unfortunately I am not allowed to reimplement the fill function. :-(

Comment: In that case, you will have to make a copy. The reinterpret of a vector<uint8_t> as a vector<uint16_t> is not safe. You might get very (un)lucky and have it work on some compiler, but I'd be surprised if there are any guarantees that something like that will work in the general case. You are, however, guaranteed that a vector stores its elements contiguously, so taking the address of the first item gives you the array of uint8_t. Any solution would have to build on that if you can't change your source type from vector<uint8_t>.

Comment: @M.K.: Well, if you are allowed to change the implementation of `Object` and to use boost, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not safe. A vector is, at the fundamental level, not an array of the type, but an object containing some data, *including* a pointer to an array of the type. That cast you do will cause a misinterpretation of the additional data. Indeed, you are not even guaranteed that the implementation of `vector` doesn't depend on the type (I doubt that this is done anywhere — with the exception of `vector<bool>` which *has* to be implemented differently — but it is definitely allowed, as long as all individual implementations conform to the standard).

You could use `boost::variant` to allow vectors of different base types to be stored in `Object::data`.

Here's how your code might look like:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

class Object
{
  boost::variant<std::vector<uint16_t>, std::vector<uint64_t> > data;
};

struct fill_visitor: boost::static_visitor<>
{
  template<typename T>
   void operator()(std::vector<T>& v)
  {
    fill(&v);
  }
};

// ...

boost::apply_visitor(fill_visitor(), object1.data);
```